# Interpertation of Motron Number

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-engineering

The Reynolds number is interpreted as the ratio of inertial to viscous forces in a flow.

Are there similar interpertations for The Motron Number?

Comment: It's the Morton number, not the Motron number. Just pointing this out because googling those terms gives different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Morton number Mo (used most commonly for analysis of bubbles) has been described as the ratio of capillary forces to buoyancy forces, but other kinds of interpretation are possible. It is a function of only the fluid type and gravity, so it is independent of actual bubble size and scale effects. Because of this, if the fluid type is changed, Mo may change, and the only way to restore the same value of Mo is to change gravitational acceleration. So you can think of Mo as the ratio of gravitational acceleration to some notion of 'molecular acceleration'. The molecular acceleration in question depends on fluid density $\rho$, viscosity $\mu$, and surface tension $\sigma$. So if you define it as:

$$
a = \frac{\sigma^3\rho}{\mu^4}
$$

The Mo is just the ratio of gravity to $a$. As to what the physical significance of $a$ is, you can see that it is higher for more dense fluids or those with higher surface tension, and much lower for those with more viscosity. A very (over)simplified way of looking at it might be: if the fluid were a blob suspended in free space, how quickly would the fluid 'pull itself' together into a sphere.

You can see the Morton number's effects on bubble shape. Lower Mo results in spherical bubbles. As Mo increases (gravity becomes stronger than the fluid's tendency to 'pull itself together'), bubbles become ellipsoidal and then start to look like [spherical caps](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-image-shows-the-bubble-shape-for-different-sizes-and-fluids-The-rows-show_fig9_258077621).